# Using LEN to qualify hostname is correct error

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a VBS script and want to use the LEN command (as one of many) checks the hostname is set correctly. Hostname is ABCD12

ComputerName is returning the correct value and the hostname starts with ABCD so it proceeds - however LEN is returning a value of 0 (not 6) even though the hostname is 6 characters long. Why is this?

```
If left(ucase(ComputerName),4) = "ABCD" then
    else     
Wscript.quit(666)

End if

iLen=Len(ComputerName)

If ilen <> 6 Then
   else
Wscript.quit(666)

End if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works

Its just that you mess up with this `If ilen <> 6 Then`

it should be

```
If left(ucase(ComputerName),4) = "ABCD" then
    else     
Wscript.quit(666)

End if

iLen=Len(ComputerName)

If ilen = 6 Then
   else
Wscript.quit(666)

End if
```

But you would better to code like this, it's way more intelligible

```
If left(ucase(ComputerName),4) <> "ABCD" then
    Wscript.quit(666)
End if

If Len(ComputerName) <> 6 Then
    Wscript.quit(666)
End if
```

or all in one

```
If (left(ucase(ComputerName),4) <> "ABCD") or (Len(ComputerName) <> 6)  then
    Wscript.quit(666)
End if
```